# Binomial probability with selective reflipping

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

What is the probability of having exactly k successes from n coins if all n coins are flipped and there are x successes, then n - x coins are re-flipped to give the additional k - x successes?

---

Example: `n = 3`, `k = 3`, `p = 1/2`, and let:
$$
f(k) = \binom {n} {k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

I tried adding the success probabilities for the following scenarios:

- All 3 success on the first attempt `f(3) = 0.125`
- 2 on the first attempt, then 1 on the second `f(2)*f(1) = 0.140625`
- 1 on the first attempt, then 2 on the second `f(1)*f(2) = 0.140625`
- 0 on the first attempt, then 3 on the second `f(0)*f(3) = 0.015625`

I get `P(3) = f(3) + f(2)*f(1) + f(1)*f(2) + f(0)*f(3) = 0.421875`.

However, doing the same for `k = 2` and `k = 1`, I get:

```
P(2) = f(2) + f(1)*f(1) + f(0)*f(2) = 0.5625
P(1) = f(1) + f(0)*f(1) = 0.421875
```

But I know this is wrong because `P(3) + P(2) + P(1) > 1`

Comment: By the reflip you are working with binomial distribution parameter $n-x$, not $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note*: It turned out in the context of [this later question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705405) that this answer may not answer the question as intended, since I assume that all failed coins are reflipped, even if the first flip yielded the desired $k$ successes, whereas the intent may have been to stop in that case.

---

A coin is a success if and only if it is a success at least once out of two flips; the probability for that is $1-(1-p)(1-p)=2p-p^2$. Thus the probability you want is

$$\binom nk(2p-p^2)^k((1-p)^2)^{n-k}=\binom nkp^k(2-p)^k(1-p)^{2(n-k)}\;.$$

Comment: When you say a coin is considered a success if it's a success at least once,  you're not counting when a single coin succeeds twice right?

Comment: For a second reflip, would the probability be
$$
\binom {n} {k}(1 - (1 - p)^3)^k((1-p)^3)^{n-k}
$$
?

Comment: @DanielK: Yes, that would be the probability for two reflips, i.e. if each coin has three chances of succeeding. On your first question: You're not actually reflipping the coins that succeed on the first flip, but you can pretend that you'd reflip them and then count them as a success independent of the second flip; thus you can generalize that a coin is a success if it succeeds on at least one flip, even if some of those flips don't actually need to be carried out -- much like you can play "best out of 5" and stop at the score of 3:0 because the winner is already determined.

Comment: @joriki I understand now, thanks! This is a bit of an extension to my question, but what if there are 3 total flips (2 reflips) where on the second flip, you can only reflip 1 failure, and on the third flip, you can only reflip up to 2 failures?
Would it be something like...
$$
\binom {3} {k}(1 - (1 - p)^1)^k((1 - p)^1)^{n-k} + \binom {1} {k}(1 - (1 - p)^2)^k((1 - p)^2)^{n-k} + \binom {2} {k}(1 - (1 - p)^3)^k((1 - p)^3)^{n-k}
$$
?

Comment: Or maybe, $P(\text{3 rerolls for 1 die}) + P(\text{2 rerolls for 1 die}) + P(\text{1 reroll for 1 die})$
$$
\binom {1} {k}(1 - (1 - p)^3)^k((1 - p)^3)^{n-k} + \binom {1} {k}(1 - (1 - p)^2)^k((1 - p)^2)^{n-k} + \binom {1} {k}(1 - (1 - p)^1)^k((1 - p)^1)^{n-k}
$$
?

Comment: @DanielK: I don't think that makes much sense, since $\binom 1k$ will generally be $0$ (except if $k$ is $0$ or $1$). Generally speaking, it's usually better to post such new questions as questions in their own right so as to avoid clutter and confusion in the comments. I'm not sure what you mean by "can", as your original question specified a specific procedure without choices -- is there now a player trying to make choices so as to reach $k$ successes? If you post a new question, let me know here and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @joriki I've written a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689859/binomial-probability-mass-function-with-selective-variable-reflipping
I've added a descriptive scenario to answer your question about having a player making choices.

Comment: @DanielK: OK, I'll give it a try. Note that the scenario you describe there differs from what I was assuming here. Since you wrote here that "then $n - x$ coins are re-flipped", I assumed that they are *always* re-flipped, not just in case the first flips failed to produce $k$ successes.

Answer (score 1):

See this poor answer as an illustration of the elegancy of the answer of @Joriki.

Let $S=S_{1}+S_{2}$ where $S_{i}$ denotes the number of successes
at the $i$-th flip. Then:

$$P\left(S=k\right)=\sum_{x=0}^{k}P\left(S_{2}=k-x\mid S_{1}=x\right)P\left(S_{1}=x\right)=\sum_{x=0}^{k}\binom{n-x}{k-x}p^{k-x}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}\binom{n}{x}p^{x}\left(1-p\right)^{n-x}=\sum_{x=0}^{k}\binom{n-x}{k-x}\binom{n}{x}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{2n-k-x}=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{2\left(n-k\right)}\sum_{x=0}^{k}\binom{k}{x}\left(1-p\right)^{k-x}=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{2\left(n-k\right)}\left(2-p\right)^{k}$$

pfff...

Comment: Thanks for this answer as it sheds additional light.
How would you generalise this for $i$ rerollls, where $j$ coins can be flipped per reroll? For example, if flipping 3 coins the first time, then up to 1 (if there was at least one failure), then up to 2 (if there were up to two failures)?

Comment: @DanielK Follow the advice of joriki: just post a new generalized question, eventually with a link to this one. Let him and me know about it here. If the question is well-posed then you increase your chances on a good answer, and laborious comments are avoided.

Comment: I've posted a new question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689859/binomial-probability-mass-function-with-selective-variable-reflipping Could you take a look? I'm curious about your input.