# Binomial probability mass function with selective variable reflipping

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

What is the probability mass function $P(N, k, p)$ where

- $N = \{N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_m\}$ is a sequence representing how many coins can be flipped (and potentially reflipped if $m > 1$)
- $k$ is number of successes
- $p$ is the probability of success per coin flipped
- There are a total number of $N_1$ coins, thus $N_1 \geq \text{max}(N_2, N_3, \ldots, N_m)$
- Only $\text{min}(N_i, N_1 - k_{i-1})$ coins are reflipped on each reflip, where $k_{i-1}$ is the number of successes before the reflip
- $P(N, 0 \leq k \leq N_1, p) = \sum_{k=0}^{N_1}P(N, k, p) = 1$

**Example**: Consider $N = \{3, 1, 2\}$

- $N_1 = 3$ coins are initially flipped
- If 3 successes occur, no coins are reflipped
- If 2 successes occur on the first flip, $k_1 = 2, \text{min}(N_2 = 1, N_1 - k_1 = 1) = 1$ coins are reflipped

  - If 0 success occurs, $\text{min}(N_3 = 2, N_1 - k_2 = 1) = 1$ coin is reflipped
  - if a success occurs, $\text{min}(N_3 = 2, N_1 - k_2 = 0) = 0$ coins are reflipped
- If 1 success occurs on the first flip, $\text{min}(N_2, N_1 - k_1) = 1$ coin is reflipped

  - If 0 successes occur on the reflip, $\text{min}(N_3, N_1 - k_2) = 2$ coins are reflipped
  - If 1 success occurs, $\text{min}(N_3, N_1 - k_2) = 1$ coin is reflipped
- If 0 successes occur on the first flip, $\text{min}(N_2, N_1 - k_1) = 1$ coin is reflipped

  - If 0 or 1 success occurs on the reflip, $\text{min}(N_3, N_1 - k_2) = 2$ coins are reflipped

I've tried the following:
$$
\text{Let}\ P_b(n, k, p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
P(N, k, p) =
P_b(N_1, k, p) + \sum_{k_1=0}^{k-1}P_b(N_1, k_1, p)\left(
 P_b(N_2, k-k_1, p) + \sum_{k_2=0}^{k-k_1-1} \ldots
\right)
$$
However I know this is wrong because $P(\{3, 3\}, 1 \leq k \leq 3, 0.5) > 1$

---

### Original questions:

What is the probability mass function $P(n, k, p, R)$ where

- $n$ is the number of coins flipped
- $k$ is the target number of successes
- $p$ is the probability of coin flip success
- $R = \{R_1, R_2, ..., R_m\}$ is a sequence denoting how many coins can be reflipped and may be empty. If the first flip doesn't succeed $R_1$ coins cans be reflipped and so on.

**Example**: $P(3, 2, 0.5, \{1, 2\})$ is the probability $k = 2$ success occur when $n = 3$ coins are flipped (and reflipped).

- If 3 successes occur on the first flip, this is considered a failure and no coins are reflipped
- If 2 successes occur on the first flip, no coins are reflipped
- If 1 success occurs on the first flip, 1 coin is reflipped (according to the sequence)

  - If 0 successes occur on the reflip, 2 coins are reflipped to try to get the second success (according to the sequence and since we currently have 1 success and 2 failures)
  - Otherwise we now have 2 successes and no coins are further flipped
- If 0 successes occur on the first flip, 1 coin is reflipped

  - If 0 successes occur on the reflip, 2 coins are reflipped to try to get 2 successes
  - If 1 success occurs on the reflip, 2 coins are reflipped to try to get one more success

Comment: "$n=3$ coins are flipped ... If $3$ successes occur on the first flip, this is considered a failure"  Does this mean too much success is a failure?

Comment: @Henry That's correct. $P(3, 2, 0.5, \{1, 2\})$ is looking for exactly $k = 2$ successes.

Comment: @Henry I revised the scenario so that it describes the full tree (not only counted success and failure cases)

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the original question, edited by the OP to reflect some of the notational changes in his rewrite of the question. Note, however, that the summation indices $k_i$ used here count the number of successes in the last flip and thus don't coincide with the variables introduced in the rewrite of the question, which represent the total number of successes up to the flip.

---

The general formula would be

$$
\binom {N_1}kp^k(1-p)^{N_1-k}+\sum_{k_1=0}^{k-1}\binom {N_1}{k_1}p^{k_1}(1-p)^{N_1-k_1}\left(\binom{\min(N_2,N_1-k_1)}{k-k_1}p^{k-k_1}(1-p)^{\min(N_2,N_1-k_1)-k+k_1}+\sum_{k_2=0}^{k-k_1-1}\cdots\right)\\
=p^k\left(\binom {N_1}k(1-p)^{N_1-k}+\sum_{k_1=0}^{k-1}\binom {N_1}{k_1}(1-p)^{N_1-k_1}\left(\binom{\min(N_2,N_1-k_1)}{k-k_1}(1-p)^{\min(N_2,N_1-k_1)-k+k_1}+\sum_{k_2=0}^{k-k_1-1}\cdots\right)\right)\;,
$$

where we can factor out $p^k$ since for an overall success the total number of successes is always $k$. In your example, this would yield

$$
p^2\left(\binom32(1-p)+\sum_{k_1=0}^1\binom3{k_1}(1-p)^{3-k_1}\\\left(\binom1{2-k_1}(1-p)^{k_1-1}+\sum_{k_2=0}^{1-k_1}\binom1{k_2}(1-p)^{1-k_2}\binom2{2-k_1-k_2}(1-p)^{k_1+k_2}\right)\right)\\
=p^2\left(3(1-p)+(1-p)^3\left((1-p)+2(1-p)\right)+3(1-p)^2\left(1+(1-p)2(1-p)\right)\right)\\
=p^2\left(3(1-p)+3(1-p)^2+9(1-p)^4\right)\;.
$$

Arguably this could be obtained more easily by just looking at the individual case than from the broad generalisation.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Your version of $P(n, k, p, R)$ is the same solution I tried in the previous question but it is wrong. For example, $P(1 \leq k \leq 3) = P(3, 3, 0.5, \{3\}) + P(3, 2, 0.5, \{3\}) + P(3, 1, 0.5, \{3\}) = 0.421875 + 0.5625 + 0.421875 = 1.40625$ which is $> 1$ and thus doesn't follow $\sum_{k=0}^nP(k)=1$. Another thing I noticed is that if $p$ is increased to $0.75$, $P(1 \leq k \leq 3) = 1.13818359375$ which seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @DanielK: These are two different problems. In that other problem, you weren't reflipping a constant number $R_1=3$ of coins, but rather all the failed coins, a variable number. Here you wrote that you're reflipping $R_1$ coins, and in your example it was ensured that there would always be at least $R_1$ failed coins to flip; I implicitly took that as given. In expressing the other question as $P(3, 3, 0.5, \{3\})$ in the present paradigm, you're now using $R_1=3$ in a situation where there may not necessarily be $3$ failed coins left to flip, so the binomial coefficients with $R_1$ are wrong.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to carry that rule over to this example. I'm going to refine the question.

Comment: I've improved my question, simplifying the probability mass function definition and clarifying the criteria.

Comment: @DanielK: That's a very bad idea. Questions and answers on this site are not just for the benefit of the person originally asking the question, but form a storehouse of knowledge. You've broken the connection between the question and the answer (e.g. by eliminating the parameters $R_i$). Please reinstate the question in the form in which I answered it, and add your new question either as a short update or, if it differs significantly, as a question in its own right.

Comment: Do you mind if I change your answer to use the new notation instead? I think I run the risk of getting a question deleted if I were to post this as a separate question.

Comment: @DanielK: Yes, I do mind :-) Because it's an answer to a different question, it's not just a matter of notation. If you think you know how my answer should be adapted to the new question, you could post your own answer (you're welcome to copy whatever you want from mine) and add a note at the top of mine saying that it refers to an earlier version of the question.

Comment: Okay I've reverted my question however your answer is still incorrect because $\sum_{k=0}^{n}P(k)\ne1$

Comment: @DanielK: I've replaced $R_i$ by $\min(R_i,n-k_i)$ to account for the fact that there may be less than $R_i$ failed coins available to reflip.

Comment: @DanielK: I see you don't mind that I do mind. Never mind. I've added a note to the answer to try to explain the resulting chaos.